# Tesseract detect lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocr, tesseract

I am working on an OCR Application in Objective-C. So far I have image recognition working fairly good but I am interested in detecting lines/rows for potentially better and nicer results.

I have both the tesseract library and leptonica library in my project. I looked at the baseapi.h for tesseract and I believe what I am looking for is the function called

```
    Boxa* GetTextlines(Pixa** pixa, int** blockids);
```

I am not sure how to use this function within my project or whether it is the correct function I seek. Can anyone offer any insight on the matter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to detect page elements (e.g blocks, paragraphs, lines, words..etc) is using PageIterator class. I don't know how to do it in Objective-C but here is a sample code in C++ for reference:

```
tesseract::ResultIterator* ri = tess->GetIterator();
while (ri->Next(tesseract::RIL_LINE)) {
  // Do whatever you want with that line
  // Recognize line's text
  char* ctext = ri->GetUTF8Text(tesseract::RIL_LINE);
  // Get line's bounding box
  ri->BoundingBox(tesseract::RIL_WORD, &left, &top, &right, &bottom);
}
```